# Order an array when filling it in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with this code: when I enter a negative value as the first value entered the program replace it with 0. If I enter it anywhere else it works fine. Why is happening that? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

int main () {
  float a[N], temp;
  int i, j;

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    scanf ("%f", &a[i]);
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
      if (a[i]<a[j]) {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;
      }
  }
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf ("%.2f  ", a[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So after you entered the first number you are looping over the *whole* array with uninitialised elements except the first one and trying to do something with them.

Comment: I have initialised the array with zeros before entering any value, but it doesn't work well yet..can you please help me?

Comment: Elaborate on  the " doesn't work well yet".

Comment: Don't use loops and conditions without braces. It makes the code harder to read and introduces hard to debug mistakes. It just leads to tears

Comment: Load your array natively, then call `qsort`. (guaranteed to be much less error prone and quite a bit more efficient)

Comment: `for (j=0; j<N; j++)` --> `for (j=0; j<i; j++)`

Comment: @Schwern fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what do you mean by "load your array natively"? I didn't understood, sorry

Comment: @accr0 Just load all elements in the order the elements are read from input, then sort it rather than trying to sort it as you add elements.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it's not depending on me, it is an assignment by my teacher

Comment: Don't get me wrong -- it is a great exercise. It would be good to hand write it once for each *bubble sort*, *heap sort*, *insertion sort*, *merge sort*, *quicksort*, *selection sort*, *shell sort*, etc... The point being, other than an educational endeavor, you are better served using the tools the standard library provides rather than rolling your on. Have fun with the coding, it is well worthwhile to know what happens under the hood.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your advice! :)

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. As others have mentioned the problem is that `a` is uninitialized so it's full of garbage until you fill it. But if you initialize it it will be full of zeros which will mess with the sorting.

The trick is to only sort up to where you've filled. That would be `i`.

```
for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
    scanf ("%f", &a[i]);
    for (j=0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i]<a[j]) {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Note it's `j < i`. It's not `j <= i` because there's no point in comparing an element to itself

Incidentally, this is an inefficient way to sort. It's basically [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), but unlike bubble sort which can stop early if the array is sorted, you'll always do [((n-1)*n)/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) operations which gets large fast. At 100 elements you're doing 4950 comparisons.

You're better off reading everything in and sorting the whole list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly that way! Anyway I'm trying to use bubble sort, but I don't know which "exemple code" I have to use, one seems to be diffrent from others and I can't use most of them...This is from an example made by my teacher but it doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/qgf2ENsa

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop (the one with index `j`) is completely undefined because it iterates through `a` before all the values in `a` have even been initialized.

To fix this, you need to separate the population of the array into its own loop, *then* do further processing on it.  From the lines:

```
   if (a[i]<a[j]) {
        temp=a[i];
       a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;  
  }
```

I'm guessing that you're trying to implement bubble sort.  This *does* need two nested loops, but the way you have it right now is wrong - array population needs to be on its own and before you even begin sorting, as stated before.

Comment: Populating the array first means, presumably with zeros, leads to problems with negative numbers.

Comment: @Schwern No, I meant populating the array with user input like the OP is presently (trying to?) do

Comment: Did you mean something like this? It doesn't work...the algorithm is from an example made by my teacher.  for (i=0; i<N; i++)  {
    scanf ("%f", &a[i]);
    for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
      for (k=N-2; k>=j; k--) {
        if (a[k]>a[k+1]) {
          temp=a[k];
          a[k]=a[k+1];
          a[k+1]=temp;   }   
                              }
                         }  
                       }